# Customize Action buttons on Custom Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

Is there a way that I could provide additional processing or logic to my Save and Cancel button?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the newform.aspx or editform.aspx page, insert a Content Script web part or Content Editor Web Part, then add the relevant JavaScript code to change the behavior for save and cancel button.

Here are some similar post for your reference:

[Change SharePoint "Save" button to "Submit" in new item forms](https://natechamberlain.com/2017/09/06/change-sharepoint-save-button-to-submit-in-new-item-forms/)

[Allow Save new item and continue in SharePoint NewForm.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417632/allow-save-new-item-and-continue-in-sharepoint-newform-aspx)